# Running a laptop fan from a battery

Tags: batteries, fan

I want to take an old laptop fan that I have and connect it to a battery so it could run just on its own.

Can you just connect a TX3 connector to a battery?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need fan working standalone - you can. We have several fans from broken PC with connectors changed to USB for easy powering them. Fan will spin on maximum speed all the time, though.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think of just getting a 3 pin to USB connector. Some times I need the absolute obvious option pointed out. Lols.

Comment: I didn't find such connector, so i cut the 3 pin one from the fan and soldered USB in its place. But it will work with 5V fans only.